# Why can't my JavaScript create this element?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head><style>
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.drag_box{
    width: 40%;
    height: 90%;
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.drag_box h2{
    text-align: center;
}
.content{
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 2px black;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    if(document.getElementById(ev.target.id).id.includes("content")){
        return;
    }
    else{ 
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
}
</script>
```

I created this function to use in a php script so it could take announcements from my school's website and automatically create content on the page. However, when run, the code does not execute at all. When the script tags are palced in the 'announcements' div, the code will execute and create the content.

```
<script>
function addContent(id, headline, content){

    var announcementContent = document.createElement('div');

    announcementContent.setAttribute('class', 'content');
    announcementContent.setAttribute('id', 'content'+id);
    announcementContent.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    announcementContent.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)');
    announcementContent.innerHTML = '<h3>'+ headline +'</h3><p>'+ content +'</p>';

    document.getElementById('announcements').appendChild(announcementContent);


}
    addContent('3','test','testest');
</script>

<div id="announcements" class="drag_box" style="float:left; margin-left: 9%;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h2>Announcements</h2>
</div>
<div id="delete_column" class="drag_box" style="float:right; margin-right: 9%;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h2>Trash Box</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future, check for errors in the Javascript console before posting here. You need to perform some basic debugging on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function before the `announcements` DIV has been added to the DOM, so `document.getElementById('announcements')` can't find it. You should be getting an error in the Javascript console saying that you can't call `.appendChild()` on `undefined`.

Put the script *after* the DIV.

```
<div id="announcements" class="drag_box" style="float:left; margin-left: 9%;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h2>Announcements</h2>
</div>
<div id="delete_column" class="drag_box" style="float:right; margin-right: 9%;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h2>Trash Box</h2>
</div>
<script>
function addContent(id, headline, content){

    var announcementContent = document.createElement('div');

    announcementContent.setAttribute('class', 'content');
    announcementContent.setAttribute('id', 'content'+id);
    announcementContent.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    announcementContent.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)');
    announcementContent.innerHTML = '<h3>'+ headline +'</h3><p>'+ content +'</p>';

    document.getElementById('announcements').appendChild(announcementContent);


}
addContent('3','test','testest');
</script>
```

Or wait until the document is loaded before calling the function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    addContent('3', 'test', 'testest');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your script after the html markup, right before `</body>` tag, otherwise the `announcements` element is not there yet when your script runs:

```
<div id="announcements" class="drag_box" style="float:left; margin-left: 9%;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h2>Announcements</h2>
</div>
<div id="delete_column" class="drag_box" style="float:right; margin-right: 9%;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h2>Trash Box</h2>
</div>

<script>
function addContent(id, headline, content){

    var announcementContent = document.createElement('div');

    announcementContent.setAttribute('class', 'content');
    announcementContent.setAttribute('id', 'content'+id);
    announcementContent.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    announcementContent.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)');
    announcementContent.innerHTML = '<h3>'+ headline +'</h3><p>'+ content +'</p>';

    document.getElementById('announcements').appendChild(announcementContent);


}
    addContent('3','test','testest');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe it was that simple.